# What is the quic server error on go and how to fix it?

Tags: linux

When I try to start the quic server on go, I get an error that it means?

Github of this project: https://github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go

```
    skly@sklypc:/test/goquic/quic-go$ go run example/main.go -bind 
    "0.0.0.0:6121"
example/main.go:20:2: cannot find package "github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go (from $GOROOT)
    /home/skly/go/src/github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go (from $GOPATH)
example/main.go:21:2: cannot find package "github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go/http3" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go/http3 (from $GOROOT)
    /home/skly/go/src/github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go/http3 (from $GOPATH)
example/main.go:22:2: cannot find package "github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go/integrationtests/tools/testserver" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go/integrationtests/tools/testserver (from $GOROOT)
    /home/skly/go/src/github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go/integrationtests/tools/testserver (from $GOPATH)
example/main.go:23:2: cannot find package "github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go/internal/testdata" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go/internal/testdata (from $GOROOT)
    /home/skly/go/src/github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go/internal/testdata (from $GOPATH)
example/main.go:24:2: cannot find package "github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go/internal/utils" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go/internal/utils (from $GOROOT)
    /home/skly/go/src/github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go/internal/utils (from $GOPATH)
example/main.go:25:2: cannot find package "github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go/quictrace" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go/quictrace (from $GOROOT)
    /home/skly/go/src/github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go/quictrace (from 
   $GOPATH)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [README](https://github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go/blob/master/README.md) (it's also at the end of the link you provided). It says you should be running Go 1.13+ (and you are running 1.10). You should also enable modules and load the dependencies.

If following that document you still have problems, you can [file an issue](https://github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go/issues).